# Unity Cardboard GVR - force default viewer profile URI in GvrViewer.cs

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

Inside GvrViewer.cs I've tried setting the defaultDeviceProfile by using:

```
public Uri DefaultDeviceProfile = new Uri ("http://vr.google.com/cardboard/download/?p=CgZPd2wgVlISBlZpZXdlch0xCCw9JdV4aT0qEAAASEIAAEhCAABIQgAASEJYATUpXA89Oggfhes-H4VrPlAAYAM");
```

We've launched in the Play & App stores and it has been reported that the app isn't defaulting to the correct device profile -  When the user scans the bar code the image distortion looks correct, however on launch the headset is not callibrated.

**I'm aware that this only works if a headset hasn't been previously paired.**

**Question 1**
How can I debug this? When we delete the app on both iOS android the previous profile is loaded :/

**Question2** Can I force this elsewhere, (maybe BaseVRDevices.cs?)

Any help would be much appreciated, unfortunately this slipped through our Q&A...